# R - dplyr how to use the i+1 loop-style condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to understand how I could use something like `[i+1]` with `dplyr`.

My data look like this

```
> head(dtat)
  id sex variable   value
1  1   m    08:00 partner
2  1   f    08:00 partner
3  1   m    08:15 partner
4  1   f    08:15 partner
5  1   m    08:30 partner
6  1   f    08:30 partner
```

I would like to check if the value for each `id` and `variable` is the same for `m` and `f`.

For example, to check if `id == 1` at `8:00` (`partner`) for `m` is also `partner` for `f` at `8:00`.

I can figure how to do it because I would like to something like `value[i+1]` here

```
dtat %>% 
 group_by(id, variable) %>% 
 mutate(as.numeric (value == value [i+1] ))
```

I also would like to check for `lag` `+1` in the `variable`. For example to compare `id == 1` for `m` at `8:00` equals `f` at `8:15`.

Any ideas ? 
Thanks

The output without the `lag` should be (`check` is the match variable in question)

```
   id variable check sex   value
1   1    08:00     1   m partner
2   1    08:00     1   f partner
3   1    08:15     1   m partner
4   1    08:15     1   f partner
5   1    08:30     1   m partner
6   1    08:30     1   f partner
7   2    08:00     0   m       *
8   2    08:00     0   f   alone
9   2    08:15     0   m       *
10  2    08:15     0   f   alone
11  2    08:30     0   m       *
12  2    08:30     0   f partner
13  3    08:00     0   m partner
14  3    08:00     0   f nuclear
15  3    08:15     0   m partner
16  3    08:15     0   f nuclear
17  3    08:30     0   m partner
18  3    08:30     0   f nuclear
```

the data

```
dtat = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), sex = c("m", "f", "m", "f", 
"m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", 
"f"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("08:00", 
"08:15", "08:30", "08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", 
"10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", 
"11:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", 
"13:30", "13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", 
"15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", 
"17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", 
"18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", 
"20:30", "20:45", "21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45"), class = "factor"), 
value = c("partner", "partner", "partner", "partner", "partner", 
"partner", "*", "alone", "*", "alone", "*", "partner", "partner", 
"nuclear", "partner", "nuclear", "partner", "nuclear")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), .Names = c("id", "sex", "variable", "value"))
```

Comment: dplyr::lag might be what you want

Comment: You can try with `lead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are interested in creating the 'check' column by comparing the current observation with the next observation, `lead` can be used.  We group by 'id', 'variable', create a logical vector with the `==` comparison and coerce it to binary by `+`.

```
 dtat %>% 
      group_by(id, variable) %>%
      mutate(check= +(value==lead(value, default=value[1L])))
#    id sex variable   value check
#1   1   m    08:00 partner     1
#2   1   f    08:00 partner     1
#3   1   m    08:15 partner     1
#4   1   f    08:15 partner     1
#5   1   m    08:30 partner     1
#6   1   f    08:30 partner     1
#7   2   m    08:00       *     0
#8   2   f    08:00   alone     0
#9   2   m    08:15       *     0
#10  2   f    08:15   alone     0
#11  2   m    08:30       *     0
#12  2   f    08:30 partner     0
#13  3   m    08:00 partner     0
#14  3   f    08:00 nuclear     0
#15  3   m    08:15 partner     0
#16  3   f    08:15 nuclear     0
#17  3   m    08:30 partner     0
#18  3   f    08:30 nuclear     0
```

Or another option would be `n_distinct` to check the `length` of `unique` elements within each group.

```
dtat %>%
    group_by(id, variable) %>%
    mutate(check=+(n_distinct(value)==1))
```

Comment: @giacomoV  It might be `dtat %>% group_by(id, variable) %>%mutate(check= +(value==lag(value, default=value[n()])))`

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of maybe something like

```
dtat %>% 
  group_by(id, variable) %>% 
  mutate(ep = 1:n()) %>% 
  mutate(check = as.numeric (value[ep == 1] == value[ep == 2]))
```